# Legend changed in a facet_grid plot after some updates to the data

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have a ggplot barplot with a `facet_grid` that worked fine until today. I have no idea why the legend is not the same thing I had before. Now instead of having 4 Status, I have many as shown in the picture.

**Code to create the dataframe:**

```
df <- structure(list(Business = c("B", "B", "B", "K", "K", "K", "K", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "O", "O", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", 
"W", "W", "W"), Status = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("Cancelled", "Closed", "In SAP", "Open"), class = "factor"), 
    `Status Count` = c(5L, 22L, 174L, 40L, 65L, 551L, 4L, 36L, 
    2L, 4L, 43L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 22L, 132L, 394L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
    66L, 106L), Percentage = c(2.49, 11, 87, 6.06, 10, 83, 1, 
    100, 3.7, 7, 80, 9, 71, 29, 3.97, 24, 71, 1, 29, 71, 3.37, 
    37, 60), tot = c(75L, 301L, 1313L, 75L, 301L, 1313L, 15L, 
    1313L, 75L, 301L, 1313L, 15L, 301L, 1313L, 75L, 301L, 1313L, 
    15L, 301L, 1313L, 75L, 301L, 1313L), business_per = c(4, 
    18, 77, 4, 18, 77, 0.88, 1, 77, 4, 18, 0.88, 77, 1, 18, 77, 
    4, 0.88, 18, 77, 1, 18, 77)), .Names = c("Business", "Status", 
"Status Count", "Percentage", "tot", "business_per"), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


#create the legend
MStatus=paste(df$Status,"(",df$tot,")",df$business_per,"%")
```

**Plot:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=`MStatus`, y=`Status Count`, x=Status, color=factor(Status))) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width = 2), stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(~Business, labeller = labeller(Business=label_wrap_gen(12))) +
  geom_text(size=4, aes(label=paste(Percentage,"%"), vjust = -0.5)) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide=FALSE) + # removes the legend for factor(Status)
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL) + #turn off vertical grid lines and removed the axis x label
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

This is the plot and the legend I am getting:

[image]

This is the legend that I am expecting (numbers are not correct, just the style matters)

[image]

**Edit 1:**

I create the following dataframe following the same steps, and the legend if fine. The only difference I can see here is only the number of records, which should not cause a problem. Is this a bug in the function?

```
df <- structure(list(Business = c("B", "B", "B", "K", "K", "K", "K", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "O", "O", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", 
"W", "W", "W"), Status = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("Cancelled", "Closed", "In SAP", "Open"), class = "factor"), 
    `Status Count` = c(5L, 22L, 174L, 40L, 65L, 551L, 4L, 36L, 
    2L, 4L, 43L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 22L, 132L, 394L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
    66L, 106L), Percentage = c(2.49, 11, 87, 6.06, 10, 83, 1, 
    100, 3.7, 7, 80, 9, 71, 29, 3.97, 24, 71, 1, 29, 71, 3.37, 
    37, 60), tot = c(75L, 301L, 1313L, 75L, 301L, 1313L, 15L, 
    1313L, 75L, 301L, 1313L, 15L, 301L, 1313L, 75L, 301L, 1313L, 
    15L, 301L, 1313L, 75L, 301L, 1313L), business_per = c(4, 
    18, 77, 4, 18, 77, 0.88, 1, 77, 4, 18, 0.88, 77, 1, 18, 77, 
    4, 0.88, 18, 77, 1, 18, 77)), .Names = c("Business", "Status", 
"Status Count", "Percentage", "tot", "business_per"), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



#create the legend
MStatus=paste(df$Status,"(",df$tot,")",df$business_per,"%")
```

and here is the chart created with the new dataframe:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect a 4-value legend, when `MStatus` is generated based on your data frame, which has precisely the values reflected in your result. You may wish to check the steps used to generate `df`, specifically the `business_per` column.

Comment: @Z.Lin I always used this code and everything was fine, even I ran the code on Friday and the chart was fine, but I ran the code today and it is not giving me the legend I always got.

Comment: Allow me to repeat this: **Look at your data**. You have more than 4 unique values in `MStatus`.

Comment: Somehow the code was generating the legend I wanted until today, anyway, do you have a suggestion how I can generate the expected legend some other way?

Comment: It is unclear what the legend values should be. If you can indicate the **actual values** expected based on this dataset, SO users should be able to suggest some code that generates them. We shouldn't have to second-guess the logic behind your expectations.

Comment: The legend would show the sum of each status and the total percentage.

Comment: I tried another dataframe using the same steps and as you can see it is working just fine, so there should be something that causes such a problem, anyone can see what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out what the problem was:

in `df` where `business_per` was used in building the legend needed to be identical numbers for each status. The culprit was the below line:

```
df$business_per[df$business_per>=1] <- round(df$business_per,0)
```

where it should have been:

```
df$business_per[df$business_per>=1] <- round(df$business_per[df$business_per>=1],0)
```